# How can I create a component that takes in inputs but is used multiple times?

Tags: angularjs, angular-components, angular1.6

[I have search list where a user can click on an item. The item gets added to a list. The list is a component in my app. The list component includes an input section where the user can input a price they want to set for that specific list item. When I type in a price for a specific list item, the inputs for the other items get updated with the same price. Click this to see an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLK4b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I can't see the code, I have a feeling it is because you are attaching the same $scope variable to all of the ng-models that you're changing, which would change every instance of that input box. By removing the `$scope`, you would make it a local variable to that instance of the list item that I'm assuming you're using `ng-repeat` on?

Change `$scope.someVarName` to `someVarName` and see if that fixes it.